# O que significa essa sintaxe de cursores/ponteiros em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor

O que significa essa sintaxe de cursores/ponteiros em SQL?

```
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE = @@SQL_MODE,
SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,
          ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Answer (score 1):

O SQL_MODE serve para definir como os comandos SQL serão tratados.

Por exemplo, o NO_ZERO_IN_DATE controla se ele vai aceitar uma data com mês 0, e o NO_ZERO_DATE define se ele vai aceitar uma data com zeros. Se eles estiverem ativados, ao tentar inserir ele vai gravar mas vai dar um warning (aviso). Se o STRICT_MODE estiver ativado, não vai gravar.

Aqui tem uma lista completa das opções disponíveis:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html